# Azure Apim authentication for apis

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, api-gateway

I have an api endpoint which is being used by multiple public clients. And each client is configured with different clientids. I am using Authorization Code flow with Oauth2 openid protocol. I would like to introduce an Azure Apim service and would like to validate the jwt token before forwarding the request to apis. Could you please let me know how can i achieve this?

Note: I can't use single client id as redirect uri is different for each client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Validate JWT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT) policy to pre-authorize requests in API Management, by validating the access tokens of each incoming request. If a request does not have a valid token, API Management blocks it. For example, add the following policy to the `<inbound>` policy section of the Echo API. It checks the audience claim in an access token, and returns an error message if the token is not valid.

```
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
    <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{aad-tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <required-claims>
        <claim name="aud">
            <value>{Application ID of backend-app}</value>
        </claim>
    </required-claims>
</validate-jwt>
```

For  more details, you could refer to the article about [Configure a JWT validation policy to pre-authorize requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#configure-a-jwt-validation-policy-to-pre-authorize-requests)

Comment: here you can configure for one client. how do we manage for multiple clients for the same api?

Comment: You can use [choose policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#choose) which is  similar to an if-then-else or a switch construct in a programming language.